# Tabularray repeat column type

Tags: tables, tabularray

Is it possible to repeat the same column type for [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)?

For a normal tabular one can use `*{5}c`, if one does not want to repeat `{ccccc}`.
I have tried it with tabularray, but it does not seem to work.

I want to have

```
{colspec = {Q[c,m,0.25\textwidth]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]}}
```

But this can not be written as `colspec = {Q[c,m,0.25\textwidth] *{4}Q[c,m]}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    Test 
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c,m,0.25\textwidth]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]}}
        a & a & a & a & a \\
    \end{tblr}
    % The one below does not work. The one above does. 
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c,m,0.25\textwidth] *{4}Q[c,m]}}
        a & a & a & a & a \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. On the very same way as at other tables packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question by just trying a bit more.
Basically, I forgot that because of the optional argument `[c,m]`, an extra set of curly braces is needed.

Thus it is possible by just:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    Test 
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c,m,0.25\textwidth]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]}}
        a & a & a & a & a \\
    \end{tblr}
    % Both work.
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c,m,0.25\textwidth] *{4}{Q[c,m]}}}
        a & a & a & a & a \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```